# Is there any way to get AT commands history that phone runned?

Tags: at-command

for example I need an AT command for changing phone data between 2G, 3G and 4G and I change it by my phone's options and I want to see which AT commands runned by phone automatically when I touch my phone. (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Both in that no phones have a history of AT command lines that have been run, and also there is not necessarily a one-to-one relation between AT commands and actions initiated by the user interface. There is a command to make phone calls (`ATD`) however when a phone call is made by the user interface it will call some internal function to start it and not issue AT commands.